# Mysql fetch all data with inclusive matching another condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

While fetching all the data with some inclusive criteria like when column name equals to "blue" or "yellow" and "colorval" not equal to "100"

```
> mysql> select * from Colors where colorname is not null;
+-----------+----------+
| colorname | colorval |
+-----------+----------+
| blue      | 100      |
| blue      | 200      |
| blue      | 300      |
| red       | 200      |
| red       | 300      |
| red       | 100      |
| red       | 400      |
| yellow    | 100      |
| yellow    | 200      |
| yellow    | 300      |
+-----------+----------+
```

and I want the result will be

```
> 
+-----------+----------+
| colorname | colorval |
+-----------+----------+
| blue      | 200      |
| blue      | 300      |
| red       | 200      |
| red       | 300      |
| red       | 100      |
| red       | 400      |
| yellow    | 200      |
| yellow    | 300      |
+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Ok, so where's your SQL with the condition? Hint: there's `AND` operand

Comment: Where is your SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the condition needed:

```
select * from colors 
where colorname is not null and (colorval <> 100 or colorname not in ('blue', 'yellow'))
```

What you need is colorval not to be equal to 100 and colorname not to be any of 'blue', 'yellow'in the same row.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6K86KvfbRhK4S9hfSCW3ri/0).
Results:

```
| colorname | colorval |
| --------- | -------- |
| blue      | 200      |
| blue      | 300      |
| red       | 200      |
| red       | 300      |
| red       | 100      |
| red       | 400      |
| yellow    | 200      |
| yellow    | 300      |
```

If you have only these 3 colors, you can simplify like this:

```
select * from colors 
where colorname is not null and (colorval <> 100 or colorname = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

So your query should be

```
select * from Colors where colorname is not null and colorname = 'blue' and colorname = 'yellow' and colorval != '100' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Colors where colorname is not null and (colorname ='blue' or colorname='yellow') and colorval <> 100;
```